# How to call this async function in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm completely new to Flutter and trying to call an asynchronous function. I keep getting

`Error: The argument type 'Future<String> Function()'can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.`

When I try to `await` the function inside an asynchronous function, it also doesn't work for me. How do I fix this?

```dart
 messages.add(ChatMessage(
    messageContent: getCompletionOpenAi(myController.text),
    messageType: "receiver",
));
```

Comment: messageContent is String?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Nice name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get the message using `await` keyword which wait for async mesaage, also mark function as `async`.

```
String msg = await getCompletionOpenAi(myController.text)

 messages.add(ChatMessage(
    messageContent: msg,
    messageType: "receiver",
));
```